# How can I find out if I can trust a potential employer?

Tags: salary, hiring-process, glassdoor

I recently got accepted for a job I applied online. I did a technical test and video interview (just me answering some questions, not talking to an actual person).
I read multiple reports online that this particular company has a bad work environment, no transparency and most important: salaries are often delayed or not paid at all. The latter gave me pause. 
How can I be sure it's not just frustrated ex-employees venting their views?
The company's website seems fine, they claim they have multiple big partners here in my country and they even list an address in the United States.

Comment: If it's multiple people saying that they delay/miss payment, it's unlikely that it is made up.  It's risky enough that I would not work there.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I be sure it's not just frustrated ex-employees venting their
>   views?

Talk to current employees - preferably employees who would be your coworkers should you get the job.

While interviewing, I have always requested to chat with my potential coworkers, folks who would work for me, and anyone else I felt could give me some insight into the company and my future boss.

I asked lots of questions about what it was like to work at the company, what it was like to work for my future boss, what they liked, what they didn't like, etc.

That way, I could get a more rounded view into the company than I could get from a few anonymous online sources with potential axes to grind.

I was always able to learn quite a lot.

Comment: Thank you, Joe. How would i go about contacting these potential coworkers? Is it ok to ask for their contact to the interviewer? I only talked to them via email.

Comment: @Guest, I agree with the answer, but don't expect blunt honesty from complete strangers. When I was asked by candidates how the working environment was, I always phrased my statement in a way that would not sound too direct (i.e. instead of telling that the boss expected 12 daily hours when paying 8, I just said "there is a lot of pressure to meet the deadlines"). I didn't know them and who they were, so exposing my real thought was too risky.